# How to Prevent External Service Interaction (DNS)

Tags: security, penetration-testing, crlf-vulnerability

What is the meaning of Remediation of vulnerabilities and how to Implement it. Please advise. Thank you.

(1)It is recommended to implement a whitelist of permitted services and hosts, and block any interactions that do not appear on this whitelist.

(2) It is recommended to block network access from the application server to other internal systems, and hardening the application server itself to remove any services available on the local loopback adapter